# Bucle while no funciona en c++

Tags: c++, while

```
int main() {

int BankBalance = 100;
int Withdrawn;
int Deposit;
int keyvalue;
int Wallet = 50;
int revenue;
int TotalMoney = Wallet + BankBalance;
int expenditures = BankBalance / 10;


printf("1 to withdraw, 2 deposit, 3 work, 0 exit. \n");

while (1)
{
    scanf("%d", &keyvalue);

    if (keyvalue == 1)
    {
        printf("Please select Ammount to Withdraw: ");
        scanf("%d", &Withdrawn);
        if (Withdrawn > BankBalance)
        {
            printf("Error, cannot Withdrawn more than your balance! \n");
        }
        if (Withdrawn <= BankBalance)
        {
            printf("Modifying Balance.... \n");
            BankBalance = BankBalance - Withdrawn;
            Wallet = Wallet + Withdrawn;
            printf("Your new balance is: %d$ \n", BankBalance);
        }
    }
    if (keyvalue == 2)
    {
        printf("Please slect ammount to deposit your wallet has %d$: ", Wallet);
        scanf("%d", &Deposit);

        if (Deposit > Wallet)
        {
            printf("Error, cannot Deposit more than your wallet has! \n");
        }
        if (Deposit <= Wallet)
        {
            printf("Depositing money \n");
            BankBalance = BankBalance + Deposit;
            Wallet = Wallet - Deposit;
            printf("Your new balance is: %d$ \n", BankBalance);
        }
    }
    else if (keyvalue == 0)
    {
        printf("You decided to Terminate the program.\n");
        break;
    }
    else if (keyvalue == 3)
    {
        printf("working... \n");
        Sleep(3000);
        revenue = 400 + TotalMoney / 2;
        Wallet = revenue + Wallet;

        printf("Added %d$ to your wallet.\n", revenue);
    }
    else if (keyvalue == 4)
    {
        printf("Not scripted yet.\n");
    }


    else if (keyvalue > 4)
    {
        printf("Not valid key.\n");
    }
    while (1)
    {
        Sleep(5000);
        BankBalance = BankBalance - expenditures;
        printf("If this message appears all is working fine.\n");
    }

}
```

Bueno, todo funciona bien excepto por el ultimo bucle `while`

```
    while (1)
    {
        Sleep(5000);
        BankBalance = BankBalance - expenditures;
        printf("If this message appears all is working fine.\n");
    }
```

alguien me dice que es lo que esta mal aqui?
perdon por las tildes mi teclado no es hispano entonces que no las puedo poner.

ademas ya intente con otros bucles como el `for(;;)` y tampoco funciona.
con que no funciona me refiero a que no hace nada, todo el programa corre normal no me da ningun error pera esa parte del codigo no se ejecuta.

Lo que deberia hacer el ultimo while es quitarte dinero cada 5 segundos por eso es infinito y no tiene condicion, pero no hace nada y tampoco me da error.

Comment: ¿Y por qué motivo funciona mal? ¿Cual es el comportamiento esperado? Si una algoritmo funciona mal es porque no se ajusta a las especificaciones, si no conocemos las especificaciones no podemos adivinar por qué no hace lo que debería

Comment: Lo siento mucho, lo voy a editar, gracias!

Comment: El bucle anidado (al que llamas último) es infinito. ¿Porqué?

Comment: ¡Buenas! Creo que falta explicar más cosas en tu código porque no se entiende muy bien lo que hace referencia cada cosa. Pero, es posible que no te funcione ese bucle porque, al salir del anterior, la condición ha cambiado y no entra en esa parte del código. Espero haber sido de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: @TheBanusco10 si te fijas no hay ninguna condicion que haya no llegar a ese while.

Comment: @Sjuan76 en c++ es en mayuscula, ya lo he intentado poner en minusculas pero no lo reconoce.

Comment: TheBanusco10 muchas gracias amigo ya me doy cuenta!

Comment: He copiado el código y me he dado cuenta de lo siguiente: 1. Te falta cerrar una llave al final que corresponde al metodo Main. 2. El codigo esta mal hecho, luego de seleccionar cualquiera de las opciones (excepto la de salir) se ejecuta la sentencia del if correspondiente al numero ingresado, por ultimo pasa al ultimo ciclo while donde no puedes salir nunca. Es decir, solo puedes elegir la opción 1 sola vez

Comment: Te has olvidado de incluir las bibliotecas, un de ellas es: #include <iostream> #include <Window.h>

Comment: Estás programando en C++ nativo o en C++ .net? Lo comento porque `Sleep` **no existe** en el estandar de C++ nativo